# Is there a way to avoid typing the dataframe name, brackets, and quotes when creating a new column in a Python/Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sas

Suppose I had a Python/Pandas dataframe called df1 with columns a and b, each with only one record (a = 1 and b = 2). I want to create a third column, c, whose value equals a + b or 3.

Using Pandas, I'd write:

```
df1['c'] = df1['a'] + df1['b']
```

I'd prefer just to write something simpler and easier to read, like the following:

```
with df1:
    c = a + b
```

SAS allows this simpler syntax in its "data step". I would love it if Python/Pandas had something similar.

Thanks a lot!
Sean

Comment: You could do `df['c'] = df1.a + df2.a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. pandas is constrained by Python's syntax rules. The expression `c = a + b` requires `a`, `b`, and `c` to be names in the global namespace and it is not a good idea for a library to modify global namespace like that (what if you already have those names? What happens if there is a conflict?). That leaves out "no quotes" part.

With quotes, you have some options. For adding a new column, you can use `eval`:

```
df.eval('c = a + b')
```

The eval method basically evaluates the expression passed as a string. In this case, it adds a new column to a copy of the original DataFrame. Eval is quite limited though, see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html) for its usage and limitations.

For adding a new column, another option is `assign`. It is designed to add new columns on the fly but since it allows callables, you can also write things like:

```
very_long_data_frame_name.assign(new_column=lambda x: x['col1'] + x['col2'])
```

This is an alternative to the following:

```
very_long_data_frame_name['col1'] + very_long_data_frame_name['col2']
```

pandas also adds column names as attributes to the DataFrame if the column name is a valid Python identifier. That allows using the dot notation as juanpa.arrivillaga also mentioned:

```
df['c'] = df1.a + df2.a
```

Note that for non-existing columns you still have to use the brackets (see the left hand side of the assignment). If you already have a column named c, you can use `df.c` on the left side too.

Similar to eval, there is a query method for selection. It doesn't add a new column but queries the DataFrame by parsing the string passed to it. The string, again, should be a valid Python expression.

Comment: I am marking this as community wiki as there are parts that could benefit from other people's knowledge. Feel free to improve.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DataFrame.eval()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html) method:

Demo:

```
In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1], 'b':[2]})

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
   a  b
0  1  2

In [19]: df.eval("c = a + b", inplace=True)

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```